# Kivy Pong Game on_touch_move moves both paddles simoultanouesly

Tags: python, kivy

I have started learning python a few months ago, and I'd like to start developing my own app. I chose Kivy and I'm following along with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgCI02-KIBc).

The tutorial uses the following code for adding touch and movement:

```
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if touch.x < self.width / 1 / 4:
        self.player1.center_y = touch.y
    if touch.x > self.width * 3 / 4:
        self.player2.center_y = touch.y
```

When I used this code both of my paddles moved at the same time. I added some brackets:

```
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if touch.x < self.width / (1 / 4):
        self.player1.center_y = touch.y
    if touch.x > self.width * 3 / 4:
        self.player2.center_y = touch.y
```

After this, I was able to move my left paddle, but my right moved the left one as well.

I ended up using the code from the kivy website, which did work:

```
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if touch.x < self.width/3:
        self.player1.center_y = touch.y
    if touch.x > self.width - self.width/3:
        self.player2.center_y = touch.y
```

Could someone explain why one code runs properly, why the other doesn't?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if conditions are different than Kivy's conditions, so they wont be returning true at the same times.

Let's look at your code:

```py
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if touch.x < self.width / (1 / 4):
        self.player1.center_y = touch.y
    if touch.x > self.width * 3 / 4:
        self.player2.center_y = touch.y

# which simplifies to ↓ because dividing by a quarter is the same as multiplying by four

def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if touch.x < self.width * 4: # will always be true (checking if touching anywhere on 4 times the screen width)
        self.player1.center_y = touch.y
    if touch.x > self.width * 3 / 4: # checking if touching last quarter of screen
        self.player2.center_y = touch.y
```

Now lets simplify Kivy's code:

```py
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if touch.x < self.width / 3: # checking if touching first third of screen
        self.player1.center_y = touch.y
    if touch.x > self.width * 2 / 3: # checking if touching last third of screen
        self.player2.center_y = touch.y
```

As you can see, your first if statement was always firing, so you would probably want to change it to: `if touch.x < self.width * 1 / 4:`
which would check the first quarter

Comment: Thank you very much